# Django 3 installed_app shows ModuleNotFoundError in custom folders

Tags: django

while using customized folders, I am having a trouble using my app correctly in `Django 3`. My folder levels are:

```
--manage.py
--mdtour
----settings
-------settings.py
----apps
------core
----templates
```

In core app my `apps.py` file is:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'
```

But i cannot use my app in `Django 3`. In settings file I tried to add the app in two ways:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mdtour.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig.core'
]
```

The error  I get:

```
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdtour.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig'; 'mdtour.apps.core.apps' is not a packa`ge
```

or

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mdtour.apps.core'
]
```

this time I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'core'. Check that 'mdtour.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig.name' is correct.
```

How can I correct this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either just name the module if you're running Django 3.2 ([automatic AppConfig discovery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#automatic-appconfig-discovery)):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mdtour.apps.core'
]
```

Alternately, name the appconfig class.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mdtour.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig'
]
```

Comment: I had to find my own answer which leads from your answer. I had to change to CoreConfig name from '''name="core" ''' to name = 'mdtour.apps.core'.